# Elasticsearch query match in array

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

```
id: 1,
name: "Jean Pantalon",
title: null,
subtitle: null,
description: null,
tags: null,
seoUrl: null,
clickCounter: 0,
model: null,
sku: null,
ean: null,
displayPrice: 0,
price: 0,
isActive: true,
isDeleted: false,
productPhotos: null,
productCategories: [
  {
    id: 1,
    productId: 1,
    categoryId: 2,
    category: {
       id: 2,
       name: "Spor",
       topCategoryId: 0,
       subCategories: null
       }
    },
 ]
```

Hello everyone, elasticseaarch has such a json yield, I want to filter it, for example the name in the productCategories te category Sports ones, how can I write this query

I'm using the c # ta nest library

Comment: Nothing to do with C.

Comment: Can you add further information about how the index is represented in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about how to do it in your lib, but in elasticsearch:

productCategories must be mapped with a "nested" data type.
Then you will be able to construct a query like this:

```
GET /my-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "productCategories",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "match": { "productCategories.category.name": "sport" } }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```